# Disabing AD-Computers in bulk from txt file

Tags: powershell

I am looking to disable numerous computer accounts that I have in text file and want to ask if someone could have a look and help me out. I have tried numerous scripts from around internet but not having too much luck so far (+8h spend and pulling my hairs). I can see there could be two different approach here, either via foreach loop with get-content or via filtering get-adcomputer but whichever I tried I get no luck. Appreciate all your help in advance.

My text file is just simple line by line with computer names like
Pc01
Pc02
and the script goes

```
$tlist = Get-Content C:\.Data\raports\test.txt

ForEach ($Computer in $tlist){
   Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq $Computer" -Properties Description
}
```

When I run this I get

> Get-ADComputer : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq PC01' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '10'.
>
> At line:1 char:31
>
> - ...  in $tlist){Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq $Computer" -Properties D ...
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADFilterParsingException
>
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
>   ```

as per second method I strugle to feed the file list in there.

All your help and advise greatly apriacited

Comment: Looks like after all that searching I have a working solution now which is 
$TimeStamp = ((get-date).toshortdatestring())
$pclist = Get-Content C:\.Data\raports\disable.txt
Foreach($pc in $Pclist)
{Get-ADComputer -Identity "$pc" |Set-ADComputer -Enabled $false -Description  "$timestamp,"}   one more thing on this I watned to ask all of you is, if there is a way to just add to description rather than replacing it. I wanted to add date of disabling it in format of   Date,[old description]

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to surround `$computer` variable.

```
ForEach ($Computer in $tlist){
    Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$Computer'" -Properties Description
}
```

[MS Documentation... Read Filter section and variable use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Thank you for your advise, it looks better now (no red) but the list comes back empty

Comment: You're not saving anything to the list.. what list are you referring to ?

Comment: I meant results, to check if it works correctly I export the results instead of actioning it just to see , later if I get the results correctly I will write actions to it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `-Filter` if you're directly specifying a machine.

```bsh
foreach ($computer in $tlist){
   Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties Description
}
```

Additionally, I find it easier to use a codeblock for filter:

```bsh
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -like "someName01" }
```

Comment: I would prefer that way too just not sure how can i point filter to list (txt/csv) file in way like Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like (check txt list for the names ) } and than pipe the result further so what is being piped further is efectively the list. Many thanks for advice